# Deploy Red5 on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, red5

Does anybody know if red5 can be deployed on Mircosoft Azure Cloud? The only hint I got was in MSDN forum:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/d58fdffe-27a4-4e77-8683-4f58fc037ff9

Thanks!
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the JDK usage is fairly normal, you should be able to make this work using a worker role that handles traffic and uses p/invoke to launch the red5 service.

Honestly, though, its likely you'll be blazing your own trail on this one.

I would recommend giving it a try ... you'll never know until ya know.  Then post blocking questions here, vs just "does it work".  Azure is new, so a lot of these "edge" scenarios are just waiting for someone to give them a whirl.  Be the first :)

good luck

Comment: :-) Okay, I will continue this thread with my results, as soon as I have them.